# Script work on Sharepoint 2013 but not Sharepoint 2010, Why?

Tags: 2010, 2013, powershell

I made this script to get all attachments from a list, it works on Sharepoint 2013 serveur but on Sharepoint 2010 I don't have any result... :

```
$webUrl = "https://site.fr"    
$library = "Contacts"
$spSite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)
$w = $spSite.OpenWeb()
$l = $w.Lists[$library]
$resultHashtable = @{}

foreach ($listItem in $l.Items)
{

    Write-Host "    Content: " $listItem.ID 
    foreach ($attachment in $listItem.Attachments)
    {
        $file = $w.GetFile($listItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $attachment)
        $linkAttachment = "http://site.fr" + $file.ServerRelativeUrl
        Write-Host "http://site.fr"$file.ServerRelativeUrl
        $resultHashtable.Add($listItem.ID, $linkAttachment)

    }

}
#Export CSV
$resultHashtable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending |
Select-Object -Property @{n='SiteURL';e={$_.Name}},Value |
Export-Csv -Path Attachments.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Result on 2013 :**

```
PS E:\Scripts> $spSite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)

PS E:\Scripts> $w = $spSite.OpenWeb()

PS E:\Scripts> $l = $w.Lists[$library]

PS E:\Scripts> echo $l


Lists                               : {Annonces, Calendrier, 
                                      73ea2520-321e-4623-b14e-9ea313889487, Contacts...}
ParentWeb                           : Citadisation Ligne A (3170)
```

**Result on 2010 :**
[image: result sharepoint 2010]

Comment: do you have the correct url on the SP 2010? One error Amal mentioned and then i am thinking about your URL, may be you dont have correct url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `$w.Lists` and not `w.Lists`

It seems you missed the **$** sign.

Comment: Thanks but I have new error :

PS C:\Users\devinfo\Desktop> echo $w

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand

Comment: On "echo $w", do you have an idea?

Comment: There is nothing when I try "$w.Title", it's a good news but the bad news is : why it didn't get my list in sharepoint 2010?? In another site in sharepoint 2013 my script get my library and attachments...